# Messages sent to my sample Telegram Bot cannot be seen by one with whom I share the bot link

Tags: telegram-bot

I have created a sample Telegram Bot. http://t.me/zOS_Telegram_bot

I am being able to send text messages to the bot. For example, check the "Testing our new Telegram Bot!!!" messages that I am being able to send to the bot. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXpbB.jpg)

However, when I share the bot link http://t.me/zOS_Telegram_bot with someone else, he/she cannot see the messages. What is it that I am missing here?

Comment: Any useful insight/s by anybody will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When someone else opens the bot link (http://t.me/zOS_Telegram_bot) it creates a new chat between the bot and the person who opened the link. This chat is independent of the chat between you and the bot. Only the person chatting with the bot can see his/her messages with the bot, that's how it is.

If you want to have a public conversation with the bot, you can create a Telegram group, add the bot to the group and then share the link to the group, not the bot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.